# Fix jQuery Lightbox Position wrt Page

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm trying to display subscription options for my blog @ TechQuark.com inside a lightbox! You can open the blog and check the same, a light box would pop up in 4-5 sec.

Everything is fine, just the issue is that the poition of this lightbox is not fixed wrt screen, i.e. it does not scroll with the page.

Here is the CSS I'm using :

```
/*Subscription Pop Up Css*/
#popupContactClose{
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration:none;
}
#backgroundPopup{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000000;
border:1px solid #cecece;
z-index:1;
}
#popupContact{
display:none;
position: fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:350px;
width:350px;
background:#FFFFFF;
border:2px solid #cecece;
z-index:2;
padding:12px;
font-size:13px;
}
#popupContact h1{
text-align:left;
color:#000000;
font-size:20px;
font-family:georgia, times new roman, arial;
font-weight:700;
border-bottom:1px dotted #D3D3D3;
padding-bottom:2px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
#popupContactClose{
font-size:20px;
line-height:14px;
right:6px;
top:4px;
position:absolute;
color:#000000;
font-weight:700;
display:block;
}
/*End Subscription Pop Up Css */
```

And here is the Pop Up Code:

```
<div id='popupContact'>
<a id='popupContactClose'>x</a>
<h1>Subscribe to Tech Guru</h1>
// Code for Subscribing Option 
</div>
<div id='backgroundPopup'/>
```

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

Just went to the site, and found this on line 800:

```
$("#popupContact").css({
"position": "fixed",
"top": 50%,
"left": 50%
});
```

both of those percentages need to be in quotes. right now, they're generating an error.